# Printing lists of dictionary values on the same line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has lists as the values:

```
my_dict = {'key1': ['foo1','foo2'],
           'key2': ['bar1', 'bar2'],
           'key3': ['foobar1', 'foobar2'}
```

I'd like to search the dictionary for multiple keys and store their values in a list:

```
keys = []
values = []
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if k.startswith(('key1', 'key3')):
        keys.append(k)
        values.append(v)
```

But when I do this I get a multidimensional (double brackets) list for values.  If I were to replace `values.append(v)` with `print(v)` I get the values on 2 separate lines.  My question is, how can I print the value lists from 2 separate keys on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many ways you can print a nested list in one line is with a comprehension:

```
print(*[i for sub in values for i in sub])
```

If you didn't *want it* to be nested in the first place, replace `append` with `extend` in `values.append(v)`.

`list.extend` takes a list (as `v` is in this case) and add all its elements to the other list. `list.append` just adds the element as is to the new list resulting in the nested structure you see.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to spring from the fact that you are separately appending more than one list to the `values` list. That is, you are doing:

```
values = []

values.append(['foo1','foo2'])  

# values = [ ['foo1','foo2'] ]

values.append(['foobar1', 'foobar2']) 

# values = [ ['foo1'...], ['foobar1'...] ]
```

In order to get values to be a single list of just the strings, use `values.extend(v)`. The [`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#typesseq-mutable) method concatenates lists, while the `append` method nests them.

```
values.extend(v)

# or:

values += v
```